# How I do add this function to console app

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, console

I have loaded an assembly called 'Mscorlib.dll' and i wanted it to list all classes within the 'Mscorlib', which it does(using reflection). Now I want to add a function whereby the user inputs a class from the assembly and it gets all the methods from that class.

How would i go around doing this? Any help would be nice

Comment: why would you want to load the MSCORLIB.DLL, that is the runtime library for all .NET executables and is referenced by default but not shown in the references in Visual studio...

Comment: You could use Net Reflector (part of Redgate) to see how in conjunction with Jon's answer below to obtain the expected results..

Comment: Hello, this is nothing too serious. I'm just practicing coding and how I can get information using reflection. Thanks for advice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Assembly.GetType(type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) to get the appropriate [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), then [`Type.GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx) to get the methods within it. (Note that the overload which *doesn't* take a `BindingFlags` will only return public methods.)

For example (no error checking):

```
Assembly mscorlib = typeof(int).Assembly;
Console.Write("Type name? ");
string typeName = Console.ReadLine();
Type type = mscorlib.GetType(typeName);
foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
{
    Console.WriteLine(method);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have already done this Jon but now I want the user to search the mscorlib for a class and that will show the methods of that class chosen. I do not want a full list of methods for the mscorlib as it seems there is too much information.

Comment: Um, that's exactly what I've shown you - note the call to `Assembly.GetType(string)` rather than `Assembly.GetTypes()`. Just call GetMethods on a *single type* rather than every type within the assembly.